# Stop form submit then trigger from a modal box

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form that when I try to send shows a modal of confirmation, I could do the same with an alert window but for the reasons of esthetic I show a modal that has a button, that button confirms the sending of the form

I would like the modal button to trigger the form, how can I do this with jquery

my code:

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" 
data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" 
id="myModalLabel">Confirmar compra</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel 
scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet 
rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
                                    <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed 
consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur 
et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.
</p>
                                    <p>
                                        <a href="" class="button button-3d 
notopmargin fleft" id="comprar" >Proceder a la compra</a>
                                    </p>
                                    <p>&nbsp;</p>



                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>   

<form method="POST" action="proceso.php" accept-charset="UTF-8" 
id="procesar"><input name="_token" type="hidden" 
value="Lj6ETkI7zq0lLWcu4nX2pGHh3kQeX6RpuazUIzHY">

<div class="col_half">


    <label for="billing-form-name">Nombre</label>
    <input class="sm-form-control" name="addressline" type="text">

</div>

<div class="col_half col_last">
    <label for="billing-form-lname">Apellido</label>
    <input class="sm-form-control" name="billing-form-lname" type="text" 
    id="billing-form-lname">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="ruc">RUC / CI</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="ruc" type="text" id="ruc">
</div>


<input class="button success" id="proc_cart" data-toggle="modal" data-
target=".bs-example-modal-lg" type="submit" value="Procesar pedido">
</form>
```

and my js

```
 var custom2=jQuery;
 custom2.noConflict();

 custom2(document).ready(function() {

    custom2( "#proc_cart" ).click( function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

    });

    custom2( "#comprar" ).click( function(event){

        $("#procesar").trigger('submit');

    });
});
```

Comment: You want to open the modal inside of your submit button's click handler, and inside the modal button's click handler you want to submit the form, just like you did. For submitting, you can also use `$('#procesar').submit()`.

Comment: to stop submission on click event return false in onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you preventDefault to stop form submit if fail requirement.

```js
$('#form1').on('submit', function(e) {
    if(
      $('#checkbox').prop('checked') == false 
    ) {
      $('.popup').show();
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      console.log('submitted');
    }
});
```

```css
.popup {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name"/>
  <div class="popup">
  <label for="confirm">Confirm</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="confirm"/>
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: thats works finde thanks.. also in my code i found an error, the final code is: custom2( "#comprar" ).click( function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#procesar").trigger('submit');

        });